# Pass certain table cell values to SQL update query

Tags: php

I feel stuck with a bit unusual situation for me up until now ... I constructed a HTML table that shows quantities from different locations by reading and rows from SQL DB into a $locations variable that is essentially an array - here's the code:

```
while ($location = mssql_fetch_array($locations)){

echo"
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px'>$location[1]</td>
<td style='text-align:center; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px'>$location[2]</td> 
<td width='50' style='text-align:center; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px'><input type='number' style='border:none;text-align:center;' class='input' name='qty_to_add[]' type='text' value='' min='1' max='999'></td>
</tr>";

};
```

[image]

But the real problem is how do I read only cells in the third column to the right, that have values imputed and pass only those to an update query that will further update only those rows that contain locations POL_12 (15 pcs + 5 more) and POL_54 (30 pcs + 7 more)?
I need to do this in a procedural way, since I am not yet familiar with OOP and PDO (but I am striving to learn it soon) :/

Please advise, all suggestions are welcome! Thank Y'all!

Comment: You will need something client-side to get the data (JavaScript, jQuery) and then use AJAX to pass the data to server-side PHP.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Hmm that's what i dreaded the most ... So PHP alone is not able to tackle this kind of a task?

Comment: No, because you have to have something gather the client-side update unless you want to get that data and submit it to the PHP process like you would do with any other form.

Comment: You can put a `<form>` around the entire table, and use hidden inputs for the `Location` columns. Then when the user submits the form, you can loop through both post variables and process the ones with the appropriate locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, following Barmar's advice (because it seemed most familiar to me in this moment) - using hidden fields in a form combined with for loop worked like a charm!

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <table style="width:100%" border="2">
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px">Location</th>
        <th style="text-align:center; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px">Qty</th> 
        <th style="text-align:center; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px">Qty to add</th>
      </tr>

<?php

    $locations = mssql_query("my query for reading item name, location and quantity per location ");

    while ($location = mssql_fetch_array($locations)) 
    {

         echo"
                <tr>
                <input style='border:none;text-align:center;' class='input' name='location_id[]' type='hidden' value='$location[0]'>
                <input style='border:none;text-align:center;' class='input' name='item_id[]' type='hidden' value='$location[3]'>
                <td style='text-align:center; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px'>$location[1]</td>
                <td width='2' style='text-align:center; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px'><input type='number' style='border:none;text-align:center;' class='input' name='current_qty[]' type='text' value='";if (!isset($location[2])) {echo "0";} else {echo $location[2];}; echo "'></td> 
                <td width='50' style='text-align:center; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px'><input type='number' style='border:none;text-align:center;' class='input' name='qty_to_add[]' type='text' value='0' min='0' max='999'></td>
                </tr>";
    };

?>


 </table></br>
 <input id="post" class="search" name="submit" type="submit" value="POST" style="position: relative"></br>
 </form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
        $location_id = $_POST['location_id'];
        $ite_id = $_POST['item_id'];
        $curr_qty = $_POST['current_qty'];
        $added_qty = $_POST['qty_to_add'];

        $rowCount = count($_POST['location_id']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) 
        {
            if ($added_qty > 0) 
            {
                $query = mssql_query("update [my-table-name] set qty_per_location = cast('$curr_qty[$i]' as decimal (5,2)) + cast('$added_qty[$i]' as decimal (5,2)) where item_id = $item_id[$i] and item_location_id = $location_id[$i]");
                echo "<br/><br/><span>Data inserted to DB successfully!</span>";
            }
        }
    }

 ?>
```

I don't want to sound disrespectful to others, that suggested possible solutions - I chose this solution merely because it was understandable for my current novice level of knowledge! Instead a big shoutout to all that sacrificed a lil' bit their time to contribute. Thank y'all!